# asp:TextBox add data attribute data-emojiable="true"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want add smiles to my asp:TextBox. I find project at Git Hub [https://github.com/one-signal/emoji-picker][1]
But in an example they used html tag - input, but I need to use asp:TextBox. And when I add all as on this site, it does not work.

Here they works example

```
<p class="lead emoji-picker-container">
   <input data-emojiable="true">
</p>
```

And here my example that doesn't work

```
<p class="lead emoji-picker-container">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" data-emojiable="true" ></asp:TextBox>
</p>
```

Comment: Have you added the required CSS and JS files in the head?

Comment: yes, I have added the required CSS and JS files in the head of the master page.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/a29xh8 here is image with they and my example of work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following on server side code to add attribute.Check for css and js files as well.

```
txtSubject.Attributes.Add("data-emojiable","true");
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added txtSubject.Attributes.Add("data-emojiable","true")   and edit my UI code, and It works!

Comment: If it solved your problem, accept as answer and do upvote.

Comment: @VeronikaKostenko you should mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem